# I get ImportError whenever I try to install outside of site-packages

Tags: pip, wsl-2, miniconda

When I try:

```
    which -a pip
```

I get

```
bailin@LAPTOP-J4I3G886:~/miniconda3/bin$ which -a pip

/home/bailin/.local/bin/pip

/home/bailin/miniconda3/bin/pip

/usr/bin/pip

/bin/pip
```

Should I get rid of most of the pips? I'm on windows 10, wsl2 ubuntu miniconda3

Comment: Why would you want to "_get rid of most of the pips_"? -- If you do not use them, then you can uninstall them of course (and most likely you would want to get rid of the corresponding Python interpreter as well). But it is perfectly fine to have multiple Python interpreters on the same machine. But again, when there are multiple Python interpreters, then I strongly recommend using the `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip` way of calling pip.

Answer (score 0):

most unix system comes with python, meaning it comes with pip too. After installing miniconda, I had another pip, that should've been overwritten but didn't. The fix is go to your bashrc file and add this:

```
alias pip=/home/usr/miniconda3/bin/pip
```

replace path with wherever your pip is

Comment: Not a good idea. You should follow this advice instead: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: isn't that the same thing @sinoroc? It says as long as I know the PATH it's alright, and I have it saved in my bashrc

Comment: I would not recommend using the `alias` technique. I have seen it break things before (sadly I can not find a link right now). The only technique I would recommend is to fix the `PATH` environment variable so that the directory containing the `python` and/or `pip` executables you want to use as default are listed first in `PATH`.